# Clearing a floated <li> correctly

Tags: height, css-float, w3c-validation

i dialy deal with `float: left;` and the CSS-reset by Eric Meyer with `class="clearfix"`. But there is one special case, i wonder how to clear a floatd element correctly: Within `<ul> ... </ul>`.

[Wrong height of the `<ul>` though using a clearer. The clearer should be within the `<ul>`. Let's try ...](http://p8472.typo3server.info/floating/error-1.png)

[Correct height, but the HTML-code ist *not valid*!](http://p8472.typo3server.info/floating/ok-1.png)

### ***How can i clear the float within the `<ul>` with valid code?***

Thanks, Johannes

Comment: Just a hint, but if you're talking code it often helps to post the relevant code *here* and, ideally, posting a live demo at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), (or other similar site) for us to play with, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: Here is the code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fqsgy/2/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply add `overflow: hidden` to the `ul` element's ruleset. Search for 'clearing floats' on Google or Stack Overflow for other solutions, though in this case this should be the cleanest.

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9sxrN/1/

Comment: Thakn you very much. That works. But i don't understand, why `overflow: hidden;` does solve the problem. I thought, that i neccessarily have to apply `cleat: left;` when i use a `float: left;`??

Comment: @Yi Jiang I too am curious about why `overflow` solves. I do know it flags the element with a special property but couldn't find a deep explanation.

Comment: @Katzenfresser @RaphaelDDL @Yi Jiang did anyone ever figure out why `ul overflow:hidden` solves the clearing issue? Very mysterious.

Comment: This seems like a mistake in the implementation of overflow and ul but at least it works. I hope it's a consistent mistake. Does anyone know if it is or not?

Comment: It is not a mistake, it works with all elements, you do however loose the ability to, well overflow anything like absolutely positioned tip of the tooltip etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, float can be applied to block-elements, that can't be inserted in UL. (neither div, neither BR you can't insert in UL). In fact you can, but it isn't valid.

So, I covered your ul with div container:

```
<div class="ul-container">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<br style="clear:both">
</div>
<b>The height of the ul-tag is ok, but the code is not valid!</b>
```

and css of ul a made css of .ul-container

```
.ul-container {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

ul li {
    float:left;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. But now there is a superfluously `<div>`-tag in the markup. For me is better, but not the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden;` on the `ul`

Comment: This may answer the question,... can you flesh it out a bit ?